# How can I generate isometric sprites based on a 3d model?

Tags: 3d, blender, isometric, 3dsmax, export

I'm wondering about the following:

I'd like to create isometric sprites for a game that I'm currently developing.

Rather than asking an artist to draw numerous sprites (which will be quite costly), I'd prefer to purchase a 3d model, for a platform such as Blender or 3DS Max, in order to render these models at different angles in an isometric perspective.

Depending on the level of detail, for each angle (0-359 degrees), I would need a sprite. Is there a specific script or feature available in either Blender, 3DS Max or a similar tool, that would suit my purpose?

Thanks a heap!

Comment: This sounds pretty close to a "which technology to use" type question. You already know you can use the tools you've mentioned to do the job, is there a specific tool you'd like to use? For example, if you wanted to use Blender, there's a stackexchange specifically for Blender when you could ask how to automate the rendering of a model at different angles.